# Requiring Two-Factor Authentication for Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, authentication

For user registration accessible on browser or app, we're considering using Facebook Login. To enhance the security and data privacy, we are considering requiring that only those users who have enabled 2FA or MFA on their Facebook accounts can use Facebook Login service.

Is there an existing method to do this?

1. Check if 2FA or MFA is enabled for a certain error?
2. IF disabled, either:

   a. Callback error (with sample meesage "2FA not enabled on current account")

   b. Request user in Facebook to enable 2FA then proceed with FB Login

Other suggested alternatives would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: Check out the link to which it changes once the fb has been logged in